# AWS EC2 instance status check is ok but server is gone

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, amazon-cloudwatch

How can I get exact status of AWS EC2 instance?

The instance status tells `ok` but actually I can't login the server (via SSH).

[image]

And Cloudwatch result is like this.

[image]

This is the period of when the server is gone.

The server didn't come back until I only stop/restart instance. (reboot didn't make server working)

How and where can I check the status of instance?

And what is the reason of this?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hello, I know this question is 3 years old, so you may not remember, but did you ever figure out what happened here? We experienced this exact same issue today.

Answer (score 1):

you can use aws cli to see the current status of your EC2 instance using the command:

`aws ec2 describe-instance-status --instance-id i-1234567890abcdef0`

Because cloudwatch is showing break in graph which means instance was not sending CPU utilization to it for that period of time. Generally happens when there is some load on the applications running on EC2 instance, consumes whole available memory of the instance to halt all the instance processes.

Actual instance status sometimes takes time to reflect on UI when things goes wrong with it.